# How to get the name of the current database from within PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using `\c <database_name>` in PostgreSQL will connect to the named database.

How can the name of the current database be determined?

Entering:

```
my_db> current_database();
```

produces:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "current_database"
LINE 1: current_database();
```

Answer (score 298, accepted):

The function [`current_database()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) returns the name of the current database:

```
 SELECT current_database();
```

It's an SQL function, so you must call it as part of an SQL statement. PostgreSQL doesn't support running functions as standalone queries, and has no `CALL` statement like some other SQL engines, so you just use `SELECT` to call a function.

Comment: Modern versions of Postgres have added support for `CALL`.

Comment: There's `SELECT current_user`, the fact that `current_database` is a function is surprising.

Comment: @SteveChavez It's because the SQL standard defines `current_user` as a magic keyword. Postgres does not want to expand the set of keywords, so anything not specified by the standard tends to be added as functions.

Answer (score 62):

you can use "\conninfo" in psql

Comment: From `psql` version 9.1.  That should cover basically all the `psql` clients out there these days, though.

Answer (score 41):

```
\c
```

prints something like

```
You are now connected to database "foobar" as user "squanderer".
```

Use this if you don't mind creating a new connection, because this is what happens. The \connect (shortened as \c) without all parameters will create a new connection identical to your current one. The current connection is closed.

See the \connect command spec on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html :

> If any of dbname, username, host or port are omitted (...)
>   , the value of that parameter from the previous connection is used.

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT * FROM current_catalog;
-- and
SELECT current_catalog;
```

...both work as well ([`catalog` is standard SQL for database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html))

Answer (score 3):

[**PostgreSQL List Databases**](https://orahow.com/listing-databases-in-postgresql/) - To list all the databases created within PostgreSQL Server.

```
postgres=# \l
postgres=# \list
```

**To Check Current database you are connected to.**

```
SELECT current_database();
```